# How combine two DensityPlot3D in only one graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, graphics3d, color

I need to combine two DensityPlot3D in only one graph but the "Show" doesn't work for that.

```
a = 1;

b = 0.56*a;

fz[x_, y_, z_] = 
  1/Sqrt[Pi * a^2 * b] * Exp[-Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/b^2]];

fy[x_, y_, z_] = 
  1/Sqrt[Pi * a^2 * b] * Exp[-Sqrt[(x^2 + z^2)/a^2 + y^2/b^2]];

fx[x_, y_, z_] = 
  1/Sqrt[Pi * a^2 * b] * Exp[-Sqrt[(y^2 + z^2)/a^2 + x^2/b^2]];

A1[x_, y_, z_] = 2*(fx[x, y, z] + fy[x, y, z] + fz[x, y, z])/Sqrt[6];

Hydro[x_, y_, z_] = 1/Sqrt[Pi * a^3] * Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/a];


plot1 = DensityPlot3D[A1[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
    ViewPoint -> Front];

plot2 = DensityPlot3D[
   Hydro[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
   ViewPoint -> Front];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

In this code , the show 'function' is just showing the first argument (plot1) and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the following would show areas at the center more clearly. More experimentation can be done with color schemes.

```
a = 1;

b = 0.56*a;

fz[x_, y_, z_] = 
  1/Sqrt[Pi*a^2*b]*Exp[-Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/b^2]];

fy[x_, y_, z_] = 
  1/Sqrt[Pi*a^2*b]*Exp[-Sqrt[(x^2 + z^2)/a^2 + y^2/b^2]];

fx[x_, y_, z_] = 
  1/Sqrt[Pi*a^2*b]*Exp[-Sqrt[(y^2 + z^2)/a^2 + x^2/b^2]];

A1[x_, y_, z_] = 2*(fx[x, y, z] + fy[x, y, z] + fz[x, y, z])/Sqrt[6];

Hydro[x_, y_, z_] = 1/Sqrt[Pi*a^3]*Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/a];

plot1 = SliceDensityPlot3D[
  A1[x, y, z], {"ZStackedPlanes", 5}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 
   5}
  , ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
  ];

plot2 = SliceDensityPlot3D[Hydro[x, y, z], 
  "CenterCutSphere", {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"];

Show[plot2, plot1]
```

---

[image]